# Using a Web API to perform 2 DB operations

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am doing my first tries with Web API and I have the following situation.
I need to perform 2 operations in a DB which must run inside a transaction:

1) Insert a record in one table (POST).
2) Update a record in another table (PUT).

Is it possible to do both in one call to a Web API?
If so, what verb should I specify: POST, PUT or another one?

With respect,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: The Http-Method doesn’t have to match the operations on the database. So it depends on, what you want to call. Usually, if you need a request-body and don’t have a id in your path, Post is preferred to Put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your Web API should not be calling your DB directly at all.  The Web API should be calling a service layer that then either calls your DB or calls repos.

The service layer can make as many calls to the DB as it needs to accomplish whatever the business rules are.

HTTP Verbs are not usually a hard rule for an action but in general, POST is for creating and PUT is for updating.  In this case, if you are creating one record and also updating another record, I would default to POST.

Comment: Oh yes, I have a class library which takes care of the DB services/operations. I am sorry I was not clear enough. I appreciate your answer.